# Implementation techniques for FSM states

Tags: language-agnostic, finite-automata, states

How do you go about implementing FSM(EDIT:Finite State Machine) states?
I usually think about an FSM like a set of functions,
a dispatcher,
and a thread as to indicate the current running state.
Meaning, I do blocking calls to functions/functors representing
states.

Just now I have implemented one in a different style,
where I still represent states with function(object)s, but the thread
just calls a `state->step()` method, which tries to return
as quickly as possible. In case the state has finished and a
transition should take place, it indicates that accordingly.
I would call this the 'polling' style since the functions mostly look
like:

```
void step()
{
  if(!HaveReachedGoal)
  {
    doWhateverNecessary();
    return; // get out as fast as possible
  }
  // ... test perhaps some more subgoals
  indicateTransition();
}
```

I am aware that it is an FSM within an FSM.

It feels rather simplistic, but it has certain advantages.
While a thread being blocked, or held in some kind of 
`while (!CanGoForward)checkGoForward();`
loop can be cumbersome and unwieldy, 
the polling felt much easier to debug.
That's because the `FSM` object regains control after
every step, and putting out some debug info is a breeze.

Well I am deviating from my question:
How do **you** implement states of FSMs?

Comment: @Skilldrick: Finite state machine

Comment: Finite State Machine (if you wasn't joking).

Comment: I edited in a clarification. Thanks for the laugh :) +1

Comment: Just to clarify, I was joking :) (Although when I see FSM the first thing I think of is pastafarianism - maybe this is the true cost of a lack of CS degree)

Comment: Damn. You got me to search for "Pastafarianism" and, geek that I am, I had to read through that epic "article". I could say you taught me a lot, so +1, but you also cost me a s**tload of time, so -1. Since this is in itself a valuable lesson: +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state Design Pattern is an interesting way of implementing a FSM:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

It's a very clean way of implementing the FSM but it can be messy depending on the complexity of your FSM (but not the amount of states).  However, the advantages are that:

- you eliminate code duplication (especially if/else statements)
- It is easier to extend with new states
- Your classes have better cohesion so all related logic is in one place - this should also make your code easier to writ tests for.

There is a Java and C++ implementation at this site:

http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/state.html

Answer (score 1):

There’s always what I call the Flying Spaghetti Monster’s style of implementing FSMs (FSM-style FSMs): using lotsa `goto`s. For example:

```
state1:
  do_something();
  goto state2;

state2:
  if (condition) goto state1;
  else           goto state3;

state3:
  accept;
```

Very nice spaghetti code :-)

Comment: Damn! Those FSMs are scaaaaary!   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did it as a table, a flat array in the memory, each cell is a state. Please have a look at the cvs source of [the abandoned DFA project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dfa/). For [example](http://dfa.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/dfa/re2dfa/dfa.hpp?revision=1.7&view=markup):

```
class DFA {
    DFA();
    DFA(int mychar_groups,int mycharmap[256],int myi_state);
    ~DFA();
    void add_trans(unsigned int from,char sym,unsigned int to);
    void add_trans(unsigned int from,unsigned int symn,unsigned int to);
    /*adds a transition between state from to state to*/
    int add_state(bool accepting=false);
    int to(int state, int symn);
    int to(int state, char sym);
    void set_char(char used_chars[],int);
    void set_char(set<char> char_set);
    vector<int > table; /*contains the table of the dfa itself*/
    void normalize();

    vector<unsigned int> char_map;
    unsigned int char_groups; /*number of characters the DFA uses,
                    char_groups=0 means 1 character group is used*/
    unsigned int i_state; /*initial state of the DFA*/
    void switch_table_state(int first,int sec);
    unsigned int num_states;
    set<int > accepting_states;
};
```

But this was for a very specific need (matching regular expressions)

Comment: Thanks Elazar. I am asking specifically about states, not the strutcture of the FSM. Since I try to model dynamic processes over time this example (albeit classy) does not help me much. My switch table would be very sparse. Usually only two or (current max)three different transitions suffice (atm).

Answer (score 1):

I remember my first FSM program. I wrote it in C with a very simple **switch** statement. Switching from one state to another or following through to the next state seemed natural.

Then I progressed to use a **table lookup approach**. I was able to write some very generic coding style using this approach. However, I was caught out a couple of times when the requirements changed and I have to support some extra events.

I have not written any FSMs lately. The last one I wrote was for a comms module in C++ where I used a "**state design pattern**" in conjunction with a "**command pattern**" (action).

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a complex state machine then you may want to check out [SMC](http://smc.sourceforge.net/) - the State Machine Compiler.   This takes a textual representation of a state machine and compiles it into the language of your choice - it supports Java, C, C++, C#, Python, Ruby, Scala and many others.